# Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ complex matrices. Then

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ complex matrices.Then

a) $\lim_{k→∞} A^k =0 ⇔$ all eigenvalues of A have absolute value less than $1$

b) $e^A\cdot e^B=e^{(A+B)}$

c) If $A$ and $B$ are nilpotent, then so is $A + B$.

d) $I + A + A^2 + A^3 + \dots$ converges ⇒ $A$ is nilpotent.

I have no idea other than $b$ which is I know that true for all matrix with same order. $c$ is false for sure!

Comment: To prove $b)$ the matrices $A$ and $B$ must commute, i.e. $AB=BA$.

Comment: The only true property here is a).

Comment: Same thing for c), you need commuting matrices.

Comment: a)$\Leftarrow$: For any matrix norm, we have Gelfand's spectral radius formula: $\rho(A)=\lim \|A^k\|^\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: @julien Yea, i made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) $\Rightarrow$ is easy. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue and $x$ a corresponding eigenvector.

Then $\lambda^kx=A^kx \to 0$. Since $x$ is not the zero vector you get $\lambda^k \to 0$.

$\Leftarrow$. Is easy to prove for Jordan forms.

(c) 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \, B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

(d) **Hint** Consider $A$ a diagonal matrix. When is $I+A+A^2+..$ convergent?

Answer (score 1):

D doesn't seem like it should be true.  Consider the one-by-one matrices and the following summation

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}=2$$

where we observe that $A=[\frac{1}{2}]$ (the one-by-one matrix).  For no (finite) power is this matrix zero and yet we get a convergent solution.

As for part A, consider this "partial answer", for diagonalizable matrices is the result obvious?

Why should B be true?  Commutativity?  Go through the proof for the ordinary number case, compare this to matrices... where does it fall apart?